# Probability of choosing a real number between 0 and 1

Tags: probability, real-numbers

When *randomly* choosing real numbers in range (0,1). 
What's the probability that if we chose x, the first decimal digit in $x^2$ is 3?

 In other words, if we chose x from (0,1), what the probability that $x^2$ looks like $0.3\square\square\square\square.....$ ?

The only thing is I'm sure about is that X~U(0,1) which means $Pr[X\le x]=F(x)=x$

 So if we wanted to choose a number which looks like $0.1\square\square\square\square.....$ this means $0.1\le x<0.2 \to Pr[0.1\le X< 0.2]=F(0.2)-F(0.1)=0.1$

Comment: What's the smallest $x$ that works?  What's the largest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$, $$0.3\leq x^2 <0.4 \;\iff \; \sqrt{0.3}\leq x < \sqrt{0.4}$$ 
Then
$$
\mathbb P(0.3\leq x^2 <0.4)=\mathbb P(\sqrt{0.3}\leq x < \sqrt{0.4}) = \sqrt{0.4} -\sqrt{0.3}\approx 0.084732975.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x$ must be in the range $[\sqrt{0.3},\sqrt{0.4})$

So the size of the range is $\sqrt{0.4}-\sqrt{0.3}=\frac{2\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{30}}{10}$ (because $\sqrt{0.4}=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt5}\cdot\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{5}$ and similarly $\sqrt{0.3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{10}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{\sqrt{30}}{10}$)

This is your probability because the range of possible values between $0$ and $1$ is $1$

Comment: Radicals are much nicer expressed in whole numbers

Comment: Yes. I noticed when I tried to solve it myself. Good point

Comment: Also overlooked that I could simply rewrite the square-roots of the decimals. I just know no examiner I've been under would accept $\sqrt{0.4}-\sqrt{0.3}$

Comment: Examiners I've been under would probably prefer the form in with radicals, mostly because writing a number in decimals is unwarrated in most courses. However, I think they'd recognise that $\sqrt{0.4}-\sqrt{0.3}$ is the same thing as $\sqrt{\frac15}-\sqrt{\frac3{10}}$, which is as good as any other notation.